# AWK regex for matching dot character

Tags: regex, awk

I have just started learning AWK, and has a basic question. My file is very simple like below:

```
h24_outdrive_s0.mt0
h24_outdrive_s.mt0
```

So if I try `"awk '$NF~/\d\.mt./' file"`, it should have matched first line.
But doesn't match anything. Looks like issue is with matching a "." as a character.

Some basic stuff is missed out here?
Please help.

Comment: `awk` does not recognize PCRE notations such as `\d` for digit.  Use `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What criteria do you have to get your data?  To use `.` as a separator you need `awk -F\. 'code'`

Answer (score 3):

use `awk '$NF~/[0-9]\.mt./'`

you will see the matched result.

btw, if your real file is just like this, you can just do `awk '/[0-9]\.mt/' file`. It does the line matching. in your file, `$NF == $0`

Comment: Also, note that `$NF~` is, in this case, not necessary since you have only 1 field.

Comment: @fredtantini your comment and my edit come almost simultaneously ;-)

Comment: Cant we have all those PCRE notations like \d in awk? Which are those other one's that cant be used like this?